# Mongo shell query is not working on mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have written a shell query which works perfectly on mongo shell but is not returning any value when run using mongoose in nodejs + typescript;

> Mongo shell

```js
db.userworks.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        user: ObjectId("607dfc9fd1ae095014ab57a0"),
        workspace: ObjectId("607dfca7d1ae095014ab57a1"),
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'workspaces',
        localField: 'workspace',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'workspaces',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$workspaces',
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'projects',
        localField: 'workspaces.projects',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'projects',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$projects',
    },
    {
      $project: {
        projects: 1,
      },
    },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$projects' } },
    {
      $sort: {
        'projects.createdAt': -1,
      },
    },
  ]).pretty()
```

But when I run the same query using mongoose in one of my routes.

> Mongoose :

```js
const projects = await UserWorks.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        user: '607dfc9fd1ae095014ab57a0',
        workspace: '607dfca7d1ae095014ab57a1',
      },
    },
    {
      $project: {
        _id: 0,
      },
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'workspaces',
        localField: 'workspace',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'workspaces',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$workspaces',
    },
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: 'projects',
        localField: 'workspaces.projects',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'projects',
      },
    },
    {
      $unwind: '$projects',
    },
    {
      $project: {
        projects: 1,
      },
    },
    { $replaceRoot: { newRoot: '$projects' } },
    {
      $sort: {
        'projects.createdAt': -1,
      },
    },
  ])
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help me with this.
Because it took me a while to make this query on shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't compare ObjectId and String.

you have to convert it ObjectId

```
mongoose.Types.ObjectId('607dfc9fd1ae095014ab57a0')
```

---

```
{
  $match: {
    user: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('607dfc9fd1ae095014ab57a0') ,
    workspace: mongoose.Types.ObjectId('607dfca7d1ae095014ab57a1'),
  },
},
```

Comment: Thanks alot Tushar. This worked for me!!
One question, is this necessary everytime we use mongoose + aggregate method?

Comment: @KaranKumar Yes, when using aggregate query you've to convert manually, mongoose will not convert it.